# Best way to find duplicate data files between two Linux machines?

Tags: linux, deduplication

I have two Debian boxes at home that have various photos, audio, video and other data files on them. They are both disorganised, I'd like to organise them and remove duplicate files between them. There's not much of a logical folder structure on either.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Unfortunately your question does not make a lot of sense - specifically a lot of files are programming related so need to be on both machined to work.  We can't really help unless we know more detail.

Comment: Fair point, sorry. I've edited to clarify, these are a mix of data files - photo, video, audio, zip files. Not looking to dedupe any system files!

Comment: How can you differentiate these files from system files? (I'm thinking this can be done by building lists of files - maybe with checksums - and then comparing these)

Comment: I can process files only within a subset of dirs (e.g. everything under 'data' on each box) - that much is fine. My best guess so far is md5 of each 'data' dir and subdirs, using Notepad++ to find duplicates between the files and then manually deleting dupes. That would work (slowly), just wondering if I'm missing a better approach.

Comment: Possibly something around `rsync` in verbose mode, with  `--checksum` (and `--dry-run` of course to avoid moving files). It also all depends on which of the two systems should keep the remaining copy.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of variants.  I think md5 is on the right track, but using SHA sums is likely slightly better.  SHA1 is probably similar speed and less likely to give a collision - although the chances of a collision is infinitesimal either way).

I would do something along the following lines -

1. On each box create a list of files with their sha1 sums with a command like

> find /path/to/files -type f -exec sha1sum {} + > pcX-sha1.lst

2. I'd then copy both files onto 1 box.  Once I've done that I'd find a list of sha checksums showing only files that are duplicates.  Once the files are in the same directory something like

> cut -f1 -d" " pcX-sha1.lst pcY-sha1.lst | sort | uniq -d > duplicateshas.lst

The last list is to find the duplicate files which you can do with a command like

> for each in $(cat duplicateshas.lst); do grep $each pcX-sha1.lst; done

The above will list the files with their names found from pcX-sha1.lst.
You can, of-course, use either file (or both files if you want to see the files location in both places as well as if they have different filenames).

Comment: I've refrained from (the risky) advice on how to delete the duplicates from one side - but rereading your comment I wonder if this us what you want. Did you need (at your risk - don't do it without a backup) me to add this?

Comment: if there is more than one copy of a file in one of the boxes this will mark it as duplicate even if there is no copy on the other box